# Align hr vertically behind div with text

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am trying to create a banner/tittle that will have a line behind the main div. I want the line and the text of the tittle to be in the middle (vertically) as shown :

[image]

The **problem** is that if I change the size of the browser, the `hr` and the text are not aligned (vertically). Below is the first version :

```css
.section {
 clear: both;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

.col {
    text-align:center;
 display: block;
 float:left;
 margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }

.span_3_of_3 { width: 100%; }
.span_2_of_3 { width: 66.66%; }
.span_1_of_3 { width: 33.33%; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .col {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }
 .span_3_of_3, .span_2_of_3, .span_1_of_3 { width: 100%; }
}

#middle
{
  background:#CCC;
  color:#FC3699;
  height:100px;
  margin-top:0;
  line-height:100px;
}

hr {
  margin-top:40px;
  border:2px solid #FC3699;
}
```

```html
<div class="section group">
 <div class="col span_1_of_3">
  <div class="topsection">
   <div class="header"><hr /></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="middle" class="col span_1_of_3">
  aaaaaaa
 </div>
 <div class="col span_1_of_3">
  <div class="topsection">
   <div class="header"><hr /></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And here is the second version. Instead of having 3 columns I could use something like the snippet below. The problem is in this line :

height:100px;
  line-height: 100px;

**where I want the height to be 100%. But the line-height cannot**:

```css
.main {
    height:100%;
    min-height:100px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap; 
}

.main > span {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    background:#F1F1F1;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
 
.main > span:before,
.main > span:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 9999px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #FC3699;
}

.main > span:before {
    right: 100%;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.main > span:after {
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <span style="vertical-align: middle;">Text</span>
</div>
```

Here is the third and best version where I only have to `text-aling:center;` the text. But even if I add it in the CSS, it does not work for a reason:

```css
.main {
    height:100%;
    min-height:100px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap; 
}

.main > span {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    background:#F1F1F1;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
 
.main > span:before,
.main > span:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 9999px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #FC3699;
}

.main > span:before {
    right: 100%;
}

.main > span:after {
    left: 100%;
}

#child {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <span><div id="child">Text</div></span>
</div>
```

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this. you have done this with :before & :after in second version. Try this  #child { display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle; width:inherit;}.

Comment: @Amit1992 I had some restrictions regarding the CSS. The first answer works fine :D Thank you all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `flexbox` is an option, this is easy - you just have to give

```
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
```

and you can do away with all the *positioning* and the *width calculations* - see demo below:

```css
.main {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.main > span {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #F1F1F1;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
.main:before,
.main:after {
  content: "";
  height: 3px;
  background: #FC3699;
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <span>Text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you have `1%` margin for `.col` and fixed position for `hr`.

I suggest using `:before` for wrapper and position it vertically-middle in wrapper. That way even if wrapper height is changed, line will be in same spot relative to wrapper (**jQuery only for demo**):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $('.col3').animate(
      {height: 300},
      2000,
      function() {
        $('.col3').animate({height: 120}, 2000);
      });
  }, 5000);
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.col3 {
  width: 33.33333%;
  height: 120px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: grey;
  color: #fc3699;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1% 0;
}
.col3:before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.wrapper:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #fc3699;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col3">
    aaaaa
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how i do it, with an icon :

```
<div class="propos_underline marginbottom">
            <div class="icon icon-cubes"></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
```

CSS :

```
.propos_underline{
  height: 1px;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #d4d8da;
  position: relative;
}

.propos_underline .icon{
   position: absolute;
   width: 70px;
   height: 40px;
   background: #ffffff;
   font-size: 30px;
   margin: auto;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   color: #d4d8da;
}
.icon-cubes:before {
   content: "\e993";
}
```

Result : 
[image]